# facing trouble in query notification system

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I read lots of post on Db design for notification system similar like facebook (not much complex) in (stakeoverflow). Finally I made two tables. 
Here are two tables, Notification and NotificationStatus. On every new post Notification table will be updated. NotificationStatus table will be updated when any user read/see or mark it as read. In NotificationStatus table I am keeping the record of users whom read or see the notification. Now I am unable to make query.

```
Notification
=========================================================
(p.k)Id | User_Id | Post_Id | CreateDate | NotificationType 

NotificationStatus
=========================================================
Id | (f.k)Notification_Id | User_Id | IsRead (boolean)
```

Here is myQuery :-

```
SELECT Notification.Time, Notification.Post_Id, Notification.User_Id
FROM  Notification 
where  Notification.User_Id in (check my freind list ) and 
Notification.User_Id not in (select * from NotificationStatus)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Unable to make query

Comment: I am facing problem in (query) NotificationStatus table, how to check read column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can get the users who have read the post.

```
SELECT 
   n.Time, 
   n.Post_Id, 
   n.User_Id
FROM
   Notification n
INNER JOIN
   NotificationStatus s ON  s.Notification_Id = n.Id
WHERE
   s.IsRead = 'True'
```

If you want to filter this query on a specific list of users, we need to know how you are passing in the users... i.e. comma seperated list, a table variable, etc.